# Reverse DNS show cname

Tags: ptr-record

I created a PTR record 
but it shows the 
this result:

```
88.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa. 86400   IN      CNAME   88.64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa.
64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN     NS      ns1.webaservers.com.
64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN     NS      ns2.webaservers.com.
```

What is issue?

My data centre say ip pool delegate to your name server
I created the  PTR zone but it show the above.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Delegations are made for whole domains. Ie, a name (sequence of labels) and everything below it is delegated somewhere.

The way IPv4 addresses are mapped to names for reverse DNS, where each octet of the address becomes one label, delegations can only happen at the octet boundaries.

This means `/8`, `/16`, `/24` and `/32` networks can be delegated.

In your case it appears to be a `/27` network, meaning that the normal delegation is not possible.

For (CIDR) networks smaller than `/24`, there's a way to still do delegations based on a `CNAME`-based hack. This is described in [RFC2317: Classless IN-ADDR.ARPA delegation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317).

The idea for such a delegation is for the last zone that can be properly delegated (the `/24`, `/16` or maybe even `/8`, depending on circumstances) to have `CNAME` records for each IP mapping of this smaller network, aliasing these to new names in a different domain and then delegating that other domain instead.

This appears to be the case here, however the nameserver that `64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa.` (the new domain they made up for this purpose) has been delegated to is responding with `NXDOMAIN` when queried about eg `88.64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa.`.

Comment: @MuhammadTayyab Assuming that `ns{1,2}.webaservers.com.` are your nameservers you should have a zone named `64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa.` and in it have records like `88.64-27.7.4.62.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR foo.example.com.`.

Answer (score -1):

[RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) (section 3.6.2) indicates that the value of a PTR record should be a canonical name.  That is, it should  not be an alias (not a `CNAME`).

> For example, suppose a name server was processing a query with for USC-
> ISIC.ARPA, asking for type A information, and had the following resource
> records:

```
USC-ISIC.ARPA   IN      CNAME   C.ISI.EDU
C.ISI.EDU       IN      A       10.0.0.52
```

> Both of these RRs would be returned in the response to the type A query,
> while a type CNAME or * query should return just the CNAME.
> Domain names in RRs which point at another name should always point at
> the primary name and not the alias.  This avoids extra indirections in
> accessing information.  For example, the address to name RR for the
> above host should be:

```
52.0.0.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA  IN      PTR     C.ISI.EDU
```

> rather than pointing at USC-ISIC.ARPA.  Of course, by the robustness
> principle, domain software should not fail when presented with CNAME
> chains or loops; CNAME chains should be followed and CNAME loops
> signalled as an error.

Comment: Surely the question seems to be about a [RFC2317](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2317)-style delegation?

Comment: how i make zone entry